# What's the "name" of a Chef resource for, besides being a default value for something else?

Tags: chef-infra

Reading about Chef [resources](https://docs.chef.io/resource.html), I note that all resources have a name. This name is often used as a default value for some argument of a given resource type; for instance, the `command` of an [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) resource and the `path` of the [`directory`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html) resource default to the `name` if not explicitly specified. But besides that, what significance does the `name` have? I want to know this in order to decide how to name my resources.

Answer (score 3):

No special significance other than the `name_property` shortcut you mentioned. Other than that, the name plus the type forms the key used for resource lookups (the `'template[/foo]'` string you see sometimes). That key needs to be unique within the current resource collection (usually global except inside providers/actions). Beyond that uniqueness requirements, you can pretty much do whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add that the name can also help (a lot!) when you're going through the logs of a chef run. Depending on how you run chef and what logs you have access to, you might just be able to see "resource_type[resource_name]", so it really helps to use more descriptive / verbose names to better explain what's going on, if it's not obvious.

Comment: having two resources named the same thing doesn't affect the idempotency of either resource.   what happens however is that the second resource clones the first resources properties.  the action is the run just like any other resource.  the cloning process however creates more confusing than it solves and is slated to get removed.  the CHEF-3694 errors which are emitted when you do this are warning you not to do it.

Comment: Ok - thanks for that clarification here! 
will edit this answer accordingly